# Copying and Renaming an Element from one XML file to another XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I can copy a node from one XML file to another using *"org.w3c.dom.Document.**importNode(Node importedNode, boolean deep)**"*
However, I can't seem to rename the Element I am copying.

I have something like:
**File1.xml**

```
<SomeCustomNode randomAttribute="aValue" another="10/10/2010">  
    <Information>  
        <Yellow name="banana"/>  
        <Orange name="orange"/>  
        <Red name="strawberry"/>  
    </Information>  
    <Some>  
        <IgnoredNode/>  
    </Some>  
</SomeCustomNode>
```

and something like this:
**FileList.xml**

```
<ListOfNodes date="12/10/2010">  
    <aCopy name="fruit" version="10">  
        <Yellow name="banana"/>  
        <Orange name="orange"/>  
        <Red name="strawberry"/>  
    </aCopy>  
    <aCopy name="vegetables" version="3">  
        <Yellow name="sweetcorn"/>  
        <Orange name="carrot"/>  
        <Red name="tomato"/>  
    </aCopy>  
</ListOfNodes>
```

So, what I am doing is taking a node (and the children) from `File1.xml` and inserting it into `FileList.xml` but renaming the `Element` and adding a couple attributes to the Element.
**Information** becomes `aCopy name="fruit" version="10"`

I am currently using an XPath expression to get the **Information** node as a NodeList (only 1 result) and then importing that into File2 like so:

```
Document docFile1 = XMLDocumentStore.getDoc("/path/to/File1.xml");  
Document docFileList = XMLDocumentStore.getDoc("/path/to/FileList.xml");  
NodeList result = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(docFile1.getFirstChild(), ".//Information");  
Node importNode = docFileList.importNode(result.item(0), true);  
// We want to replace aCopy fruit with the updated version found in File1  
NodeList fruitNode = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(docFileList.getFirstChild(), ".//aCopy[@name=\"fruit\"]");  
Node replaceNode = fruitNode.item(0).getParentNode().replaceChild(importNode, fruitNode.item(0)); // probably a better way to do this  
// Now we want to replace the Element name as it is still set to Information  
docFileList.renameNode(replaceNode, null, "aCopy"); // Error: oracle.xml.parser.v2.XMLDOMException: cannot add attribute belonging to another element
```

I get other errors if I move the code around a little, things like:
 *cannot remove or replace node it is not a child node of the current node* etc.

Would this be better via XSLT? All I'm doing is taking a specific node (and it's sub-nodes) and putting it into another XML file, but replacing the Element name and adding 2 attributes (with values). It would be the same node for each file (File1 ... File###) and would be renamed in the same way, the attribute values are taken from the source file (e.g. File1.xml for my example) and the sub-nodes don't get changed (Yellow, Orange, Red in my example).
Cheers!

Comment: This would be much better suited to Scala, which has native XML support. XSLT is a world of pain arguably greater than that in which you currently find yourself. If you are curious, look to http://www.scala-lang.org/node/131 - If you are not curious then I wish you good fortune in your search for an answer.

Comment: I would recommend using XSLT especially for a simple transformation like this. Using DOM is not a very good solution if you're dealing with large XML files.

Comment: @ Synesso - Slightly off-topic but, I'm Tempted by Scala though I would have to learn & get it accepted by my team etc. though I can use Scala inside a Java project right? Add the Scala to the class/build path and then setup a Scala class to interact with the Java classes?

Comment: @ gcores - I think the fileList would not go beyond 700 "aCopy" nodes and each "aCopy" node would have between 2 and 8 sub-nodes (Orange/Yellow/Red from example). Is that too large for DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an Oracle XML Parser?

If you use the defaults provided by `javax.xml` you won't get this error:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.XPathAPI;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Document docFile1 = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("File1.xml"));
    Document docFileList = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("FileList.xml"));
    NodeList result = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(docFile1.getFirstChild(), ".//Information");
    Node importNode = docFileList.importNode(result.item(0), true);  
    // We want to replace aCopy fruit with the updated version found in File1  
    NodeList fruitNode = XPathAPI.selectNodeList(docFileList.getFirstChild(), ".//aCopy[@name=\"fruit\"]");
    Node replaceNode = fruitNode.item(0).getParentNode().replaceChild(importNode, fruitNode.item(0)); // probably a better way to do this  
    // Now we want to replace the Element name as it is still set to Information  
    docFileList.renameNode(replaceNode, null, "aCopy"); 

    print(docFileList);

}
```

Prints out:

```
<ListOfNodes date="12/10/2010">  
    <Information>  
        <Yellow name="banana"/>  
        <Orange name="orange"/>  
        <Red name="strawberry"/>  
    </Information>  
    <aCopy name="vegetables" version="3">  
        <Yellow name="sweetcorn"/>  
        <Orange name="carrot"/>  
        <Red name="tomato"/>  
    </aCopy>  
</ListOfNodes>
```

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Seems to be a problem with my imports. Will have to fix that. I've been building up my tool based on an already existing project but I can swap the imports around or fix it just for this one class. Cheers!